# JavaFx - Set two 'setOnAction' to the same button

Tags: java, button, javafx, action

I get EventHandler from another class, and I want to set this EventHandler and other ActionEvent to the same button. It is possible?

The code is following.
The button is: "btnAdd".

```
public void addActionListener(EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandlerSetNotSave){
    btnAdd.setOnAction((e)-> {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("pictures file format",
                "*.TIF","*.JPG","*.PNG","*.GIF","*.JEPG");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilter);
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (file != null &&
                url.equals(emptyImageUrl)? true:alertMessageWarning("The viseme will change, and previous viseme will be delete.")) {
            setImage("file:"+file.toString());
            changeAfterSaved=false;
        }
    });
    btnAdd.setOnAction(eventHandlerSetNotSave);

    btnDelete.setOnAction((e)-> {
        changeAfterSaved=true;
        setImage(emptyImageUrl);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call the `addEventHandler()` method instead of `setOnAction(...)`:

```
btnAdd.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, (e)-> {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("pictures file format",
            "*.TIF","*.JPG","*.PNG","*.GIF","*.JEPG");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilter);
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (file != null &&
            url.equals(emptyImageUrl)? true:alertMessageWarning("The viseme will change, and previous viseme will be delete.")) {
        setImage("file:"+file.toString());
        changeAfterSaved=false;
    }
});
btnAdd.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, eventHandlerSetNotSave);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way you could do that with JavaFX out of the box, but there is a simple workaround. You can create a simple class to just forward your events to multiple handler like this:

```
public class MultipleEventHandler<T extends Event> implements
        EventHandler<T> {

    private Collection<EventHandler<T>> handler;

    public MultipleEventHandler(Collection<EventHandler<T>> handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(T event) {
        handler.forEach(h -> h.handle(event));
    }
}
```

You can then pass all your event handler to the constructor and use this class as your event handler.

```
MultipleEventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = new MultipleEventHandler<>(asList(e, eventHandlerSetNotSave));
btnAdd.setOnAction(handler);
```

Comment: Why not just use the standard API?